# How many turns left to construct?

Tags: civilization-5

In Civilization IV (G&K), I order my workers to build a road, then cancel so that they only put in one turn's worth of construction. I order them this way then move on to the next tile before actually completing the road. I do this all along the intended path until each intended tile only has one turn left of construction, then move back along the road, technically finishing in the shortest time possible. I do this because I don't have to pay for road until it's constructed, so this minimizes maintenance cost.

However, two turns before it's done, the game will not tell me accurately how many turns are needed to finish construction. The game does not tell me if there are one or two turns left to complete the road. I must remember whether or not there are one or two turns left to construct something with a worker. I don't do this with just roads either, but anything that takes a number of turns to construct via worker. I believe that this failure of the GUI is a bug. Is there a way to see whether or not there are one or two turns left to construct something?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the game does tell you exactly how many turns are left.  If you left click on the Workers' icon, information about the selected worker appears in the bottom left corner.  In the box, it will list what task the worker is currently working on followed by a set of parentheses with a number - e.g. (3).  The number represents the number of turns left before completion of the task - e.g. (3) means that three turns are left for the worker to finish the task.

Comment: Turn 266: Not out of moves. Construct a fort in 4 Turns, says the tool-tip. Click, Construct a Fort (3) says the worker info box in the bottom-left. Turn 267: Construct a Fort (2). Not out of moves. 2 turns, says the tool-tip. Click, out of moves, 2 turns still. Turn 268: Tool-tip: No time. Construct a Fort (1). Click, out of moves, Construct a Fort (1). Turn 269: Construct a Fort (1). Tool-tip: no time. Click, out of moves, fort constructed. Can someone confirm this outside of OnLive?

Comment: @Nite The trick there looks like the fact that sometimes when you click, it has already executed that turn, while others it hasn't.  If you click build, it immediately executes that order and updates to say how many more turns will be needed.  So if it says 1 after you've done that, you don't want it to build anymore.

Comment: Later, I'll test if a problem like this occurs regardless of "forcing" the action.